# Does spring transaction management locks database?

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I am new in spring transaction management. I have learn in hibernate there is locking concept for transaction management.
Does spring have such internal working Mechanism.

Comment: Please go through spring doc. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are locking concepts implemented in Spring. So if you are using Spring Data JPA you can simply use the `@Lock` annotation to decide on how you want to lock within your transaction. You can find further information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#locking). In this example the Annotation is only used on the Repository interface methods, but as far as I know you can also use this on Service methods annotated with `@Transactional`.